# Is it standard to sign documents using the computer?

Tags: contracts, contracting, legal

As I am traveling I find it increasingly more difficult to find a place where I can print, sign and then scan the documents I am asked to fill. Is it normal to just add the signature with some program to the PDF file in the US and send the file back?

I am asking because, while I was trying to find whether or not it's legal, I couldn't find any decent information because of the hundreds of tutorials on **how** to make it ([Jurassic Park quote](http://quotegeek.com/quotes-from-movies/jurassic-park/397/)).

So I am asking if it's common in the US to do this (and if you know in a non-legal-binding with IANAL and all if it's legal).

Comment: Anyone can copy paste a signature.

Comment: Anyone can also sign a piece of paper and scan it. The correct way to do this is with digital signatures. PDF (at least adobe) does support this.

Comment: I would recommend asking you manager whether it would be acceptable to sign with an electronic signature. Some companies I've worked for accept them, others don't (admittedly this is in the UK).

Comment: I would think that it's not all that difficult to find somewhere to print and scan a document in the US. I don't have any issues doing so even in the third World. You just actually have to look for a place rather than try and find ways around it,

Comment: which documents do you need to sign?

Comment: If you have a smartphone you can download the pdfscanner. I have it on the iPhone and signed several documents (including the mortgage on my house) and sent it. The app allows you to save it as a image or pdf that you can attach to emails. Probably the most useful app on my phone, to be honest. This doesn't answer your question or solve the problem of printing it, but I figured I'd put it out there.

Comment: Every hotel I have stayed at since the late 1980s has had a computer and printer available for the guests. Every office supply store and places like teh UPS and KInko stores have printers. There are small printers you can take with you to hook up to your laptop when travelling.

Comment: I sign everything digitally and have never had anyone question it. How would they even know the difference?

Answer (score 2):

I sign many documents using my chipped ID card and putting in a PIN. This adds a digital signature, with your name, date, and ID number. Because it requires a PIN to use, that is proof that you are the person signing the document. If you have the capability, this is perfectly acceptable.

If you don't have something similar, and you are asking about adding an image of your signature to your PDFs, then you need to talk to your management or HR or whomever is asking for the forms.

Comment: The USA doesn't have ID cards

Comment: @Pepone Neither does the UK, but my office does. He doesn't mean National ID cards, he means one issued by the company for the purposes of using the software.

Comment: @JohnHC the op doesn't mention this "company Id" card at all

Comment: @Pepone The OP doesn't mention at all what they mean by "add the signature with some program", so I gave an option.